# python program bug help

Tags: python, multithreading

I've got an exam coming up soon. I've been looking through the past paper, this question keeps bugging me. I can't seem to find what the bug in the program could be because I'm quite new to all this. Can anyone help me out?

The following program contains a bug.  Determine what kind of problem the program exhibits, and show how it can be fixed.

```
import threading
import time
import random
#the list "data" must contain two values.  
#The second must always be equal to the first multiplied by 4

class GeneratorThread(threading.Thread):
    #Thread for generating value pairs
    def __init__(self,data):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.data=data
    def run(self):
        while True:
            #Pick a new first number
            num=random.randint(0,100)
            self.data[0]=num
            #simulate some processing 
          #to calculate second number
            time.sleep(1)
            #Place second value into ata
            self.data[1]=num*4
            time.sleep(1)
class ProcessorThread(threading.Thread):
    #Thread for processing value pairs
    def __init__(self,data):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.data=data
    def run(self):
        while True:
            #Process current data
            num1=self.data[0]
            num2=self.data[1]
            print "Values are %d and %d."%(num1,num2)
            if num2!=num1*4:
                print "\tDATA INCONSISTENCY!"
            time.sleep(2)
if __name__=="__main__":
    data=[1,4]
    t1=GeneratorThread(data)
    t2=ProcessorThread(data)
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
```

Comment: sorry about the code layout dont how to do it so it lays out properly

Comment: For future reference, you can either manually put four spaces before each line, or select all the code you've pasted in and press the `1010` button in the toolbar.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#Computing

Comment: Run the code. Does it act like a program that's behaving like its designer intended, or one that's constantly spitting out all-caps error messages? What do you think the actual "intent" of the code was, and how can you make it behave that way?

Comment: Is it just me or should this person not be asking for help with schoolwork?  -1

Comment: Schoolwork questions are fine here there's little difference between asking us and asking your educator, except our answers will be better of course :-) What's not liked is people asking for homework _answers_ without having put _any_ effort into it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a [race condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) between your two threads. Basically, there is a time between setting `data[0]` to something before setting `data[1]` to four times that value.

If the second thread comes in and checks the values during that time, the data inconsistency will occur.

You may *think* the two threads refer to their own `data` information but that's not the case. They are both references to the main `data` array. If you really want them to have their own data arrays, you should change:

```
self.data=data
```

into:

```
self.data=data[:]
```

in both `init` functions.

Otherwise (and this is the more likely case where you want to share the data), you need to ensure your threads are properly synchronised so that the data is always consistent, something like using a mutex:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import threading
import time
import random
#the list "data" must contain two values.
#The second must always be equal to the first multiplied by 4

class GeneratorThread(threading.Thread):
    #Thread for generating value pairs
    def __init__(self,data):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.datamutex=datamutex         # save reference to the mutex.
        self.data=data
    def run(self):
        while True:
            #Pick a new first number
            num=random.randint(0,100)
            self.datamutex.acquire()     # get the mutex.
            self.data[0]=num
            #simulate some processing
          #to calculate second number
            time.sleep(1)
            #Place second value into ata
            self.data[1]=num*4
            self.datamutex.release()     # release it to allow other thread
                                         #  to run now that data is consistent.
            time.sleep(1)
```

```
class ProcessorThread(threading.Thread):
    #Thread for processing value pairs
    def __init__(self,data):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.datamutex=datamutex         # save mutex reference.
        self.data=data
    def run(self):
        while True:
            #Process current data
            self.datamutex.acquire()     # lock (can only happen if data consistent).
            num1=self.data[0]
            num2=self.data[1]
            self.datamutex.release()     # release it to allow updates.

            print "Values are %d and %d."%(num1,num2)
            if num2!=num1*4:
                print "\tDATA INCONSISTENCY!"
            time.sleep(2)

if __name__=="__main__":
    datamutex = threading.Lock()         # Create the mutex for both threads.
    data=[1,4]
    t1=GeneratorThread(data)
    t2=ProcessorThread(data)
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
```

Now locks aren't the *only* way to synchronise threads but they're fine for this particular case.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for explicit locking if you stick to thread safe ways of updating and reading the data. In this case using the fact that slice operations on lists are thread safe.

```
import threading
import time
import random
#the list "data" must contain two values.  
#The second must always be equal to the first multiplied by 4

class GeneratorThread(threading.Thread):
    #Thread for generating value pairs
    def __init__(self,data):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.data=data
    def run(self):
        while True:
            #Pick a new first number
            num=random.randint(0,100)
            data0=num
            #simulate some processing 
          #to calculate second number
            time.sleep(1)
            #Place second value into ata
            data1=num*4
            self.data[0:2]=data0,data1
            time.sleep(1)
class ProcessorThread(threading.Thread):
    #Thread for processing value pairs
    def __init__(self,data):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.data=data
    def run(self):
        while True:
            #Process current data
            num1,num2=self.data[0:2]
            print "Values are %d and %d."%(num1,num2)
            if num2!=num1*4:
                print "\tDATA INCONSISTENCY!"
            time.sleep(2) 
if __name__=="__main__":
    data=[1,4]
    t1=GeneratorThread(data)
    t2=ProcessorThread(data)
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
```